How to properly convert Detectron2 instance segmentation (Mask R-CNN) model to onnx model
I'm trying to convert a Detectron2 model to onnx. When I try to run the onnx model afterwards I get the following error:
Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Load model from /dbfs/redacted/model_simp.onnx failed:Node (If_3504) Op (If) [TypeInferenceError] Mismatched tensor element type: inferred=bool declared=uint8

The problem is related to the masks the model returns. I believe they are uint8 in pytorch and onnx expects boolean (or the other way around). When I exclude the masks the onnx model runs without error.
Here's the code:
import torch
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer
from detectron2.export import TracingAdapter
import onnx
import cv2
import onnxruntime as ort
import numpy as np

cfg = get_cfg()
model_file_name = "COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml"
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file(model_file_name))
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = 'cpu'
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = 'model_final.pth'
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.5
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.BATCH_SIZE_PER_IMAGE = 64
cfg.TEST.EVAL_PERIOD = 200
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 2
cfg.SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH = 2
cfg.INPUT.MASK_FORMAT= 'bitmask'
cfg.SOLVER.BASE_LR = 0.001
cfg.SOLVER.MAX_ITER = 2000
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 3

class TorchModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cfg) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.model = build_model(cfg) # Build Model
        _ = DetectionCheckpointer(self.model).load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)  # Load weights
        self.model = self.model.eval() # In evaluation mode
    
    def forward(self, INPUT):
        if isinstance(INPUT, (np.ndarray, torch.Tensor)): # it supports just 1 image
            INPUT = [{"image":INPUT}]

        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = self.model(INPUT)[0]['instances']
        
        boxes, labels, scores, masks = outputs.pred_boxes.tensor, outputs.pred_classes, outputs.scores.detach(), outputs.pred_masks.to(dtype=torch.uint8)

        return boxes, labels, scores, masks
model = TorchModel(cfg)
model = model.eval()

metadata = MetadataCatalog.get(VALID_DATA_SET_NAME)
dataset_valid = DatasetCatalog.get(VALID_DATA_SET_NAME)
im = cv2.imread(dataset_valid[7]['file_name'])
im_torch = torch.as_tensor(im.astype("float32").transpose(2, 0, 1))
inputs = [{"image": im_torch}]

traceable_model = TracingAdapter(model, inputs, None)

torch.onnx.export(traceable_model, (im_torch,),
                  "model.onnx", 
                  opset_version=17,
                  input_names = ['image'],
                  output_names = ['boxes', 'labels', 'scores', 'mask'],
                  dynamic_axes={'image' : {1 : 'height', 2: 'width'},
                                'boxes' : {0 : 'num_boxes'},
                                'labels' : {0 : 'num_boxes'},
                                'scores' : {0 : 'num_boxes'},
                                'masks' : {0 : 'num_boxes', 1 : 'mask_height', 2 : 'mask_width'}
                                })

session = ort.InferenceSession("model.onnx")
im_test = cv2.imread('demo_image.png')
im_test_torch = torch.as_tensor(im_test.astype("float32").transpose(2, 0, 1))

im_test_numpy = im_test_torch.detach().numpy()

outputs = session.run(None, {"image": im_test_numpy})

As you can see I already tried to cast the masks to uint8, without success. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Below are some of the last nodes of the onnx model graph:
Node: Squeeze_3500, OpType: Squeeze, Inputs: ['onnx::Squeeze_3566', 'onnx::Squeeze_3567'], Outputs: ['N']
Node: Constant_3501, OpType: Constant, Inputs: [], Outputs: ['onnx::Equal_3569']
Node: Equal_3502, OpType: Equal, Inputs: ['N', 'onnx::Equal_3569'], Outputs: ['onnx::Cast_3570']
Node: Cast_3503, OpType: Cast, Inputs: ['onnx::Cast_3570'], Outputs: ['onnx::If_3571']
Node: If_3504, OpType: If, Inputs: ['onnx::If_3571'], Outputs: ['bitmasks']
Node: /model/model/Cast_11, OpType: Cast, Inputs: ['bitmasks'], Outputs: ['/model/model/Cast_11_output_0']
Node: /model/Cast, OpType: Cast, Inputs: ['/model/model/Cast_11_output_0'], Outputs: ['mask']


You can use export_model.py (link to source code) to export the model.
During the export process, I used STABLE_ONNX_OPSET_VERSION=11, but I also tried using versions 16, 17, and 21. While the export may succeed and the model is verified with Neptron, using onnxruntime to load the ONNX session may still cause an error with some opset versions.
Command:
python tools/deploy/export_model.py --config-file [file config] --sample-image [img with size you want] --output weight --export-method tracing --format onnx MODEL.WEIGHTS [file pretrained model]  MODEL.DEVICE [device]


The export does not include dynamic axes. Also the returned results were empty...
